# d3.js v4.9 Get the calculated width of selected element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3.js library to create SVG charts. I use the width of the SVG element to determine the x.range, x-axis, ...)

```
<svg id="etendues" style="display:inline-block;width: calc( 100% - 501px);min-height:300px;float:left;"></svg>
...
let margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40};
let width = parseInt(d3.select('#etendues').style("width")) - margin.left - margin.right;
```

Everything was working as intended with d3.js 4.7.4. as `d3.select('#etendues').style("width")` was returning the 'calculated' width of the element in pixels (also worked nicely on resize event).

However, since version [4.9](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases) the behaviour of the selection.style method has changed.

> "Change selection.style to return the inline style, if present."

`d3.select('#etendues').style("width")` now returns `'calc( 100% - 501px)'` which is the textual inline style of the element which is not usable in my case (it works if I set an inline width style in pixels, but I don't want that).

Is there a workaround to obtain the old behaviour of getting the real calculated width in pixels of the element ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply access the DOM node of the element using d3's [`selection.node`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_node) (i.e. `d3.select(...).node()`), and then use `window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue(<prop>)` to get the computed width<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue)</sup>. In your case, you can:

1. Store the reference, i.e. `const etendues = d3.select('#etendues').node();`
2. Get the width using native JS:

   - `window.getComputedStyle(etendues).getPropertyValue('width')`, or
   - `window.getComputedStyle(etendues).width`

Just remember to use `parseInt()`, since it will return a pixel value--you are already doing that though, so all is good :)

To wrap it up, you can use the following code:

```
const etendues = d3.select('#etendues').node();
let margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40};
let width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(etendues).width) - margin.left - margin.right;
```

Here is a slightly modified proof-of-concept example, meant to simply log the retrieved width to console:

```js
const etendues = d3.select('#etendues').node();
console.log(parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(etendues).width));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="etendues" style="display:inline-block;width: calc( 100% - 501px);min-height:300px;float:left;"></svg>
```

References to MDN docs:

1. [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)
2. [`window.getPropertyValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue)

Comment: Good answer. By the way, you don'n need `getPropertyValue('width')`, just `.width` will return the same.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks! I almost forgot about that ;) updated my answer

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks ! Very useful to have robust code as I use it in an home-made library.

Comment: @Terry Nice answer! You might also quote the message accompanying the commit which changed the behaviour as it provides some insight in the rationale behind it: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/commit/e7c72a68028ecba3db709e28de22f6a0b2f0ce81